# Pandas using apply function to create a column based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-3.11

I'm trying to create column C that is equal to column A if column B is not nan, else make column C equal to column B.

I've tried this apply function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'b': [np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 2]})
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['a'] if np.isnan(row['b']) else row['b'])
```

But get this error: `KeyError: 'b'`

I still don't understand why I get this error if the dataframe clearly does have a 'b' column. Am I using the apply function the wrong way?

Comment: Just use `df['c'] = df['b'].fillna(df['a'])`, this will be much more efficient that `apply` with `axis=1` (which is what you forgot)

Comment: You are, you need to specify `axis=1` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the suggestion, although for my use case I will need to use an apply function since my function is more complicated than the lambda function I mentioned above.